# How to remove first 10% and last 10% value of data in R

Tags: r

I have a set of data, for example

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

I find out that the first 10% and last 10% of the data is extreme value and I would like to remove it.
Is there any function in R can do this?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Does this answer your question?

```
> quantile(x, c(.1, .9))
10% 90% 
1.9 9.1 
> x[x>quantile(x, .1) & x<quantile(x, 0.9)]
[1] 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
>
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO. Please include any code you've tried yourself and the expected output as well.

In this case it is heavily dependant on the type of data you have. Say in your case you have a single vector, we can achieve this in several ways.
Manually we could do

```
#Some vector we want to subset
v <- rnorm(100) 
n <- length(v)
k <- n / 10
length(v[-c(1:k, (n - k + 1):n)])
[1] 80
```

or we could abuse the `quantile` function to create the indices for us

```
k <- quantile(seq(n), probs = c(.1, .9))
length(v[k[1]:k[2]])
[1] 80
```

Now this works only if we have simple objects such as `list` or `vectors`. If you have a `data.frame` you will need to take dimensions into account. Here we likely want to remove a subset of rows

```
df <- data.frame(v = rnorm(100), z = rnorm(100))
n <- nrow(df)
k <- n / 10
nrow(df[-c(1:k, (n - k + 1):n), ])
[1] 80
```

again we could use the quantile function to create our indices for us

```
k <- quantile(seq(n), c(.1, .9))
nrow(df[k[1]:k[2], ])
[1] 80
```

However knowing that the first and last X values are outliers is a rare case. It is more common to have a subset of rows (not necessarily subsequent rows) that are outliers. For this you would specify which are outliers in an index (similar to the first manual example) and then simply remove these values.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually I have generated 1000 random sample. rnorm(1000), and order it in ascending order. I would like to remove the first 10% and last 10% of this data.

Comment: My pleasure. In this case either of the first two suggestions in my answer will achieve just this. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Using `between`.

```
library(data.table)
x[do.call(between, c(list(x), quantile(x, c(.1, .9), names=F)))]
# [1] 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

---

*Data:*

```
x <- 1:10
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need `quantile`. Below is one example via using `cut`

```
> x[!is.na(cut(x,quantile(x, c(.1, .9))))]
[1] 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```